# Summing based on multiple rows

Tags: javascript, database, csv, d3.js

I have a massive csv that look like

```
name      year     count
Sam       2012       3   
Mike      2012       4
Jeff      2013       5
.
.
.
Sam       2012       8  
Sam       2013       8       
Jeff      2013       9
```

How do I use d3 to only sum the count if both name and year are the same?
So, the output should be

```
name year sum
Jeff 2013  14
Sam  2012  11
Sam  2013  8
Mike 2012  4
```

I've tried this so far

```
var test = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.name })
    .key(function(d) { return d.year })
    .rollup(function(v) { total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.count }) })
    .object(data);
```

but this outputs the total as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the *output* described in your question is not the actual output you're looking for, that's just the structure you'd like your CSV had so you could get the output you want: `d3.csv`, like `d3.csvParse` (used internally), returns an **array of objects**. That also applies to `d3.tsv` (the CSV in your question looks like a TSV... fortunately it really doesn't matter, the solution is the same be it a CSV or TSV).

That being said, do not use a `d3.nest`, which will be deprecated soon anyway. You also cannot use a row function, since row functions are called for **every row** in the CSV. So, the simplest alternative is using a pure JavaScript solution to create your new data structure.

For instance, using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const csv = `name,year,count
Sam,2012,3
Mike,2012,4
Jeff,2013,5
Sam,2012,8
Sam,2013,8
Jeff,2013,9`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d3.autoType);

const newData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  const foundObject = acc.find(function(d) {
    return d.name === curr.name && d.year === curr.year;
  });
  if (foundObject) {
    foundObject.count += curr.count;
  } else {
    acc.push(curr)
  };
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```